# How to read a raw text file from SD card?

Tags: android

I am trying to get my app's version name, as well as the version name saved in a .txt file on my SD card named ver.txt. I can easily get my app's version but how do I read the version stored in my .txt file?

```
// get local apk version code
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info = null;
try {
    info = manager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// get version code from downloaded .txt file
//

// compareVersions
if (info.versionCode >= 1) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "up to date!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "updates are available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: You cannot read the file as a regular text file? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12421888/3741176)

Comment: Which is the content of file? Just the version number?

Comment: yes sir, just numerical numbers, no alphabets, and it reads "101"

Comment: that link is for `string` right?

Comment: Why you dont use a Preference?

Comment: I think you should use `SharedPreference` for storing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the complete solution, but you get the idea.

```
int updateVersionCode = info.versionCode;

try {
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard, "version.txt");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = null;

    if((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        updateVersionCode = Integer.parseInt(line);
    }
    br.close();
}catch (Exception e) {
    //Handle errors!
    e.printStackTrace();
}


if (info.versionCode  < updateVersionCode) {
    //The local version is minor, so updates are avaliable...
}
```

Comment: `if (info.versionCode >= 1) {`  where `info.versionCode` is the local apk version and `1` will be replaced by the version it fetches from the .txt file. hope this is making sense

Comment: i don't understand why int updateVersionCode = info.versionCode;?

Comment: why are they equal?

Comment: @MaggotSauceYumYum Because if read from text file fails, `info.versionCode` and `updateVersionCode` will be equals on `if`, and nothing will be updated.

Comment: it always stays on the if statement. both versions , my apk's and the one on the txt file are same (101)

Comment: i changed it to `if (  updateVersionCode >= info.versionCode) {` and it is still the same. it always stays on the if statement

Comment: If the version of app and the content of text file are the same, what you are trying to do?

Comment: it always fires the if statement and shows the up to date! toast

Comment: I updated my answer. check if there is some exception.

Comment: where is it even getting the value to int from the .txt file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116706/discussion-between-allan-pereira-and-maggotsauceyumyum).